# Can't update Packages (go: error loading module requirements)

Tags: go

I want to update my package but when i run -v command to get latest updates the command line hit an err

```
go get -v ./...
```

what happens?

```
> go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.17.11 go: finding
> github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.17.7 go: finding
> github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.16.32 go:
> github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.17.7: git -c protocol.version=0 fetch
> --unshallow -f https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in
> /Users/fly/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/cb1953cbdfd14fc2ffce4dfd06487e8d5a0c96da00d00bdef65874ff644eaa26:
> exit status 128:  warning: redirecting to
> https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/    fatal: Unable to create
> '/Users/fly/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/cb1953cbdfd14fc2ffce4dfd06487e8d5a0c96da00d00bdef65874ff644eaa26/shallow.lock':
> File exists.
> 
>   Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.    an
> editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes     are
> terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process   may have
> crashed in this repository earlier:   remove the file manually to
> continue. go: github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.16.32: unknown revision
> v1.16.32 go: github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.17.11: unknown revision
> v1.17.11 go: error loading module requirements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear here:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.    an
>   editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes     are
>   terminated then try again.

When you run `go get` the `git` command is used to load everything. So there is another process using git.

Just end the other git command and it will work.

Comment: actually i did that but still same problem nothing uses git so he process continued to run it's another problem i thing ,and as a mention i deleted the Users/fly/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/cb1953cbdfd14fc2ffce4dfd06487e8d5a0c96da00d00bdef65874ff644eaa26/shallow.lock' 
but still same problem

Comment: When you use modules you normaly should just run `go build`. If you want to update a package you should just change the version inside your import path.